# Javascript variable scope in file API

Tags: javascript, scope, fileapi

I have a function that takes two arguments: *entry*, a file entry (from a drag and drop source), and *fileName*, the name of said file.

I'm not sure if this helps, but *entry* is declared as:

```
var entry = evt.dataTransfer.items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();
```

I want to create an array that describes information about this entry, that array includes the file name, file size, a file size that is represented in a different unit, and the unit being used to represent said file.  I print my array to the console at two different points, once inside of the .file method (I apologize if I'm using incorrect terminology) and once more outside.  The console doesn't print a value for the array when it is outside of the .file method.

Could I please get help on how to fix this and also why this happens?  I declare my variable outside of the .file method so I thought my variable scoping was correct, but apparently this is not so.

Here is my function:

```
function getFileSize(entry,fileName)
{
    var fileData = [];
    var i = 0;
    var byteSize = ['B','kB','MB','GB','TB'];

    fileData.push(fileName);

    entry.file(function(file)
    {
        var fsize = file.size;
        var i = 0;
        fileData.push(fsize);

        while(fsize > 1024)
        {
            fsize = (fsize / 1024);
            i++;
        }

        fileData.push(fsize.toFixed(2));
        fileData.push(byteSize[i]);

        console.log(fileData);
    });

    console.log(fileData);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `.file()` is asynchronous. The `fileData` hasn't been populated yet, when the last `console.log(fileData)` is called. If you want to return `fileData` to the caller, 
you'll need to make `getFileSize()` async as well:

```
function getFileSize(entry, fileName, callback) {
  ...
  var fileData = [];

  entry.file(function(f) {
    ...
    callback(fileData);
  });
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response! I didn't know about callbacks, learned something new :)